# Spartacus Product Configurator - Authorization Code Flow breaks deep links

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am currently working on implementing the authorization code flow with Auth0 for our Spartacus application. The authentication works fine and I can navigate the page from the root. However when I try to access a deep link, e.g. /configure/vc/product/entityKey/key I get redirected to the Homepage. Same behaviour when I refresh the page.

I observed that the pages request gets canceled and instead the Router routes to "/". I don't see any Fail Actions being fired by ngrx.

Debugging the flow, I believe it has to do with the AuthService.checkOAuthParamsInUrl() method, which throws an exception in line

`const result = await this.oAuthLibWrapperService.tryLogin();` (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/auth/user-auth/facade/auth.service.ts)

The method seems to check for the code inside the url, which is not available in deep links. I assumed it would take the token from the local storage if available.

Am I on the wrong track, or is the only possiblity to adjust the behaviour of the AuthService? If so, how should I go on with it?

Spartacus Version: 3.4.3.
rxjs Version: 6.6.7

[EDIT] My AuthConfig:

```
provideConfig(<AuthConfig>{
  authentication: {
    OAuthLibConfig: {
      responseType: 'code',
      redirectUri: environment.spartacus.auth.redirectUrl,
      customQueryParams: {
        connection: 'main-tenant-oidc',
        audience: 'my-audience'
      }
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://my-auth.auth0.com',
    client_id: 'id',
    client_secret: 'secret',
    loginUrl: '/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint: '/oauth/token',
    userinfoEndpoint: '/userinfo',
    revokeEndpoint: '/oauth/revoke'
  }
})
```

[EDIT]
The AuthGuard confirms that the user is logged in, i.e. the isUserLoggedIn() function returns true.

[EDIT]
Updated to Spartacus 4 following the reference structure, no change of behaviour. I am configuring authentication via

`routing: {protected: true}`

My Feature Module looks like this, knowing that I definitly dont need all of the imports:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {OrderConfirmationModule, ReplenishmentOrderConfirmationModule} from "@spartacus/checkout/components";
import {CheckoutOccModule} from "@spartacus/checkout/occ";
import {
  AuthModule,
  CartModule,
  CartOccModule,
  CostCenterOccModule,
  ExternalRoutesModule,
  ProductModule,
  ProductOccModule,
  UserOccModule
} from "@spartacus/core";
// TODO:Spartacus - 'ProductVariantsModule' was removed from @spartacus/storefront. Use @spartacus/product/variants feature-library instead. To benefit from lazy loading it by default, consider removing the module import and running the command 'ng add @spartacus/product --features=Product-Variants'.
// TODO:Spartacus - 'UserComponentModule' - Following module imports 'LoginModule', 'LoginFormModule', 'LoginRegisterModule', 'RegisterComponentModule' were removed. Those modules are now part of @spartacus/user.
import {
  AddressBookModule,
  BannerCarouselModule,
  BannerModule,
  BreadcrumbModule,
  CartComponentModule,
  CartPageEventModule,
  CategoryNavigationModule,
  CmsParagraphModule,
  FooterNavigationModule,
  HamburgerMenuModule,
  LinkModule,
  MyCouponsModule,
  MyInterestsModule,
  NavigationEventModule,
  NavigationModule,
  NotificationPreferenceModule,
  OrderCancellationModule,
  OrderDetailsModule,
  OrderHistoryModule,
  OrderReturnModule,
  PaymentMethodsModule,
  ProductCarouselModule,
  ProductDetailsPageModule,
  ProductFacetNavigationModule,
  ProductImagesModule,
  ProductIntroModule,
  ProductListingPageModule,
  ProductListModule,
  ProductPageEventModule,
  ProductReferencesModule,
  ProductSummaryModule,
  ProductTabsModule,
  ReplenishmentOrderDetailsModule,
  ReplenishmentOrderHistoryModule,
  ReturnRequestDetailModule,
  ReturnRequestListModule,
  SearchBoxModule,
  SiteContextSelectorModule,
  StockNotificationModule,
  TabParagraphContainerModule,
  WishListModule
} from "@spartacus/storefront";
import {
  CloseAccountModule,
  ForgotPasswordModule,
  RegisterComponentModule,
  ResetPasswordModule,
  UpdateEmailModule,
  UpdatePasswordModule,
  UpdateProfileModule
} from "@spartacus/user/profile/components";
import {ProductVariantsFeatureModule} from './features/product/product-variants-feature.module';
import {LoginFormModule, LoginModule, LoginRegisterModule} from "@spartacus/user/account/components";
import { UserFeatureModule } from './features/user/user-feature.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    // Migrating the StorefrontModule
    ProductDetailsPageModule,
    ProductListingPageModule,
    ExternalRoutesModule.forRoot(),

    // Migrating the CmsLibModule
    HamburgerMenuModule,
    CmsParagraphModule,
    LinkModule,
    BannerModule,
    CategoryNavigationModule,
    NavigationModule,
    FooterNavigationModule,
    BreadcrumbModule,
    SearchBoxModule,
    SiteContextSelectorModule,
    AddressBookModule,
    OrderHistoryModule,
    OrderCancellationModule,
    OrderReturnModule,
    ReturnRequestListModule,
    ReturnRequestDetailModule,
    ProductListModule,
    ProductFacetNavigationModule,
    ProductTabsModule,
    ProductCarouselModule,
    ProductReferencesModule,
    OrderDetailsModule,
    PaymentMethodsModule,
    CartComponentModule,
    TabParagraphContainerModule,
    OrderConfirmationModule,
    ProductImagesModule,
    ProductSummaryModule,
    ProductIntroModule,
    BannerCarouselModule,
    MyCouponsModule,
    WishListModule,
    NotificationPreferenceModule,
    MyInterestsModule,
    StockNotificationModule,
    ReplenishmentOrderHistoryModule,
    ReplenishmentOrderConfirmationModule,
    ReplenishmentOrderDetailsModule,
    CloseAccountModule,
    UpdateEmailModule,
    UpdatePasswordModule,
    UpdateProfileModule,
    ForgotPasswordModule,
    ResetPasswordModule,

    // Migrating the StorefrontFoundationModule
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    CartModule.forRoot(),
    ProductModule.forRoot(),

    // Migrating the OccModule
    CartOccModule,
    CheckoutOccModule,
    ProductOccModule,
    UserOccModule,
    CostCenterOccModule,

    // Migrating the EventsModule
    CartPageEventModule,
    NavigationEventModule,
    ProductPageEventModule,
    ProductVariantsFeatureModule,

    // UserComponentModule Substitution
    LoginModule,
    LoginFormModule,
    LoginRegisterModule,
    RegisterComponentModule,
    UserFeatureModule
  ]
})
export class SpartacusFeaturesModule {

}
```

[EDIT]
Important to notice: Our tokens are not being validated by SAP Commerce Backend. So it may be an issue with the error responses, that differ from the native error responses.

Thanks for any hints :)

Answer (score 0):

The throw from this method is not unusual and is handled with the try-catch. This confirms even that if this throws we don't invoke `this.authRedirectService.redirect();` method.

In my opinion the depth of the url should not make any difference to Auth handling. I would look either into other guards that could cause some redirect or into this code specific to this configurator routes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed our custom module from the imports, but still the same behaviour. This morning I cleared the token from the local storage manually and ended up in requests spamming `/pages?pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=%2Flogin&lang=en&curr=USD`. Resulting in 401s, because the Authroization header is not being sent with the request, which is kinda confusing. I really dont know where this might be coming from.

Comment: I got it to work by changing the reponseType to `'code token'`. Does it make sense? I feel like I am just working myself around the security there, but since I can see the `/login/callback?code=qu_h_6C-sGtNlKIr&state=Fw1kCiLB_nqn-rIxTUDmhXVFkw6ea1gq` request it feels quite ok?! Can you tell me if I am just fooling myself with this solution while the real issue is something else?

Comment: I'm still thinking that the real issue might be there, but this solution just might have hidden it. If you are using `code` then the `token` is not needed. But from the security side using code is better than auth flows